# Speed up reading an Excel File in Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I wonder if there is any way to speed up reading an Excel file with powershell. Many would say I should stop using the *do until*, but the problem is I need it badly, because in my Excel sheet there can be 2 rows or 5000 rows. I understand that 5000 rows needs some time. But 2 rows shouldn't need 90sec+.

```
$Excel               = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $Excel.Visible       = $true
    $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$Path = EXCELFILEPATH
$Workbook            = $Excel.Workbooks.open($Path)
$Sheet1 = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(test)

$URows = @()
Do {$URows += $Sheet1.Cells.Item($Row,1).Text; $row = $row + [int] 1} until (!$Sheet1.Cells.Item($Row,1).Text)
$URows | foreach {
$MyParms = @{};
$SetParms = @{};
```

And i got this 30 times in the script too:

```
If ($Sheet1.Cells.Item($Row,2).Text){$var1    = $Sheet1.Cells.Item($Row,2).Text
$MyParms.Add("PAR1",$var1)
$SetParms.Add("PAR1",$var1)}
                 }
```

I have the idea of running the $MyParms stuff contemporarily, but I have no idea how. Any suggestions?

Or

Increase the speed of reading, but I have no clue how to achieve that without destroying the "read until nothing is there".

Or

The speed is normal and I shouldn't complain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appending to an array with the `+=` operator is terribly slow, because it will copy all elements from the existing array to a new array. Use something like this instead:

```
$URows = for ($row = 1; !$Sheet1.Cells.Item($row, 1).Text; $row++) {
           if ($Sheet1.Cells.Item($Row,2).Text) {
             $MyParms['PAR1']  = $Sheet1.Cells.Item($Row, 2).Text)
             $SetParms['PAR1'] = $Sheet1.Cells.Item($Row, 2).Text)
           }
           $Sheet1.Cells.Item($Row,1).Text
         }
```

Your `Do` loop is basically a counting loop. The canonical form for such loops is

```
for (init counter; condition; increment counter) {
  ...
}
```

so I changed the loop accordingly. Of course you'd achieve the same result like this:

```
$row = 1
$URows = Do {
           ...
           $row += 1
         }
```

but that would just mean more code without any benefits. This modification doesn't have any performance impact, though.

Relevant in terms of performance are the other two changes:

1. I moved the code filling the hashtables inside the first loop, so the code won't loop twice over the data. Using index and assignment operators instead of the `Add` method for assigning values to the hashtable prevents the code from raising an error when a key already exists in the hashtable.
2. Instead of appending to an array (which has the abovementioned performance impact) the code now simply echoes the cell text in the loop, which PowerShell automatically turns into a list. The list is then assigned to the variable `$URows`.

Comment: Sounds nice, could you explain shortly how that works? especially the first line of your improval. and what is wrong with my $MyParms.Add - will it still work as/with splatting?? I would like to understand the reason for transforming everything into new code, except only the += to ++

Comment: Thank you very much! Got it! Adapted my script. Works much better!

Answer (score 3):

Don't use Excel.Application in the first place if you need speed. You can use an Excel spreadsheet as an ODBC data source - the file is analogous to a database, and each worksheet a table. The speed difference is **immense**. Here's an [intro on using Excel spreadsheets without Excel](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/09/11/how-can-i-read-from-excel-without-using-excel.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much for that link. Not easy to comprehend, but I will try it!

Comment: I have asked another question about ODBC databases. Could you have a look at it? I am stuck.

Comment: A little late, but I think you mean an OLEDB data source.

Comment: Looks like that technet link got updated.
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2008/09/12/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-read-from-excel-without-using-excel/