# Is it possible to speed up an Excel query within PowerShell?

Tags: excel, powershell, oledb

I am currently using the following query to add a specific row (with 10 columns) from an Excel spreadsheet (~1500 rows and hosted on SharePoint) to an array in PowerShell.

```
$connection = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection

$connectstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=$Source;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES'"; $connection.ConnectionString = $connectstring

$connection.open()

$cmdObject = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand

$query = "Select * from [Sheet1$] 
WHERE [Sheet1$].[Test] = '$Test'"
$cmdObject.CommandText = $query
$cmdObject.CommandType = "Text"
$cmdObject.Connection = $connection

$oReader = $cmdObject.ExecuteReader()

[void]$oReader.Read()
    $Global:oData = New-Object PSObject
    $oData | Add-Member NoteProperty List1    $oReader[0]
    ...
    $oData | Add-Member NoteProperty List10   $oReader[9]

$oReader.Close()
$cmdObject.Dispose()
$connection.Close()
$connection.Dispose()
```

This works absolutely fine, however it is often quite slow. Is there any way in which I could speed up the query? I can't add the entire excel sheet into an array, as the data changes throughout the day and is queried regularly.

I've found other questions, such as [Speed up reading an Excel File in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19314858/speed-up-reading-an-excel-file-in-powershell) however that doesn't seem relevant to this particular issue.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I think it is slow because it is not local? It has to be downloaded from sharepoint? Please try the same with a local excel and you'll see its real performance

Comment: Questions regarding optimization of working code are better handled at [Code Review - Excel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel).

Comment: I've just put the file on my desktop and it's about the same in terms of speed, minimally faster perhaps, but still noticeably slow.

Comment: @Jeeped - thank you, I've asked the question there now and will see if anyone has an idea